# SQLite join in embedded database tables

Tags: c#, sqlite, join, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I am currently writing a Windows Store Application for Windows 8 and I am using SQLite for the persistence on the embedded database in a class library for windows apps.  I am trying to join data from two different tables in my embedded database but SQLite keeps throwing a not supported exception from their GenerateCommand method.

I do currently have data in both tables and they both have a questionId in each table to join on.  I've tried two different methods which both throw the same error.

The first method:

```
    var q = (from gameTable in db.Table<Model.GameSaved>()
                 join qTable in db.Table<Questions>() on gameTable.QuestionId equals qTable.QuestionId
                 select qTable
                ).First();
```

The second method:

```
    var q =
                (from question in db.Table<Model.GameSaved>()
                 select question
                ).Join(db.Table<Questions>(), 
                       game => game.QuestionId, 
                       questionObject => questionObject.QuestionId,
                       (game,questionObject) => questionObject)
                 .First();
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing here but it has to be something simple and obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not missing anything. Joins via linq are not supported by Sqlite-net at this time. You can work around this by providing your own SQL and using the `Query` method. Your first query from above would look something like:

```
var q = db.Query<Questions>(
    "select Q.* from Questions Q inner join GameSaved G"
    + " on Q.QuestionId = G.QuestionId"
).First();
```

If you are so inclined, the `Query` method also supports parameters. From the [Sqlite-net readme](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net):

```
db.Query<Val>(
    "select 'Price' as 'Money', 'Time' as 'Date' from Valuation where StockId = ?",
     stock.Id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seemed like SQLite-net didn't support joins because it didn't make sense but now I understand the restrictions more.